Prevent ToolStripMenu to "reopen" when keeping Alt key for long
Maybe this is a dumb question, but I never noticed. Since I'm creating a skin for my WinForm I have to manage the behavior and events of the strip menus. So I'm handling the selection in many ways (to handle the color of the elements) and I discovered that a menu is closed by pressing Alt only if you briefly press it.
If you keep it pressed long enough, the menu highlights (to open) again the first item in the menu. Do you happen to know how long that time would be? Because I'm handling events and my take is "if the menu is open, you press and then release Alt key, then the menu is closed" but it is not the case if you press it and release it much later so I have to handle this, possibly not in a dumb way, like "guessing"...?
I can handle the event maybe with a timer if I know how long that is, like, count time with the tick event and if Alt is kept pressed for long enough then I consider the menu "still open", like a boolean true, otherwise it's false. But for that, I should in fact know the duration needed.

And how are you handling the rendering of the Menu items? The ToolStrip uses a ToolStripProfessionalRenderer, which can be initialized with a custom ProfessionalColorTable. You can derive custom objects from both and skin any of the ToolStrip's items the proper way, overriding the default behavior when it seems appropriate. Those methods notify when some state changes and allow any kind of customization

what do you mean by rendering?

A procedure that generates graphic content and selects it into a canvas (which, technically, is referred to as the render) -- See the notes and code in here: Change space between Image and Text in ContextMenuStrip. The code is in a slightly different language, but it's originally written in C#. I can repost it in this language -- The overridable methods of the ToolStripProfessionalRenderer are called whenever parts of a ToolStrip / MenuStrip / MenuItems need rendering, so you can provide your own graphic procedures

i kinda tried following MS docs for the ToolStripProfessionalRenderer class but it's quite demanding, meaning, I just need to create a minimal thing, then I can start from there step by step, but MS docs straightly make you create a full professional menu that goes beyond my needs...
